# Calculate the frequency of words within dataframe (file excel)

Tags: python, text, count, frequency

I have one table with these data within of a file excel csv:

```
"text"           "label"
Bla Bla Bla Bla     0
Bla Bla Bla Bla     0 
Bla Bla Bla Bla     1 
Bla Bla Bla Bla     0
Bla Bla Bla Bla     1
```

I would like to get the frequency of word in class 1 and in class 0. How can I do?
I split data on basis of lable, using this code:

```
s=1
df1 = df[df['label'] >= s]
s2=0
df2 = df[df['label'] >= s]
```

Answer (score 0):

so, basically I don't understand your code. **But what i assume is:** 
you have a dataset, splitted into two arrays of strings. And want to know how many times each of them is here, or know what percent of all words they are.
Am I right? 
If yes, here is my approach/pseudocode. 
 First of all im writing this for only one of these two arrays. Second will be the same.

- Create next 2xN array (named further: *AM*)
- Make a for loop iterating through your array
- Make an if statement that checks if word your currently on is on the AM (using for loop going through AM and comparing strings). If it is already on AM, add 1 to AM[place of word][1], if not add this word to AM[end][0]
  So thats kinda it. Its simple "map" type approach.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).